# Problem with forwarding/back-propagation of the concatenation of parameters from a set of separate pytorch models

Tags: pytorch

I would like to **concatenate the parameters of a set of models and forward them through a network** (in order to get an output, calculate a loss, and back-propagate), but it seems that the graph is "broken"(?) -- even though it doesn't raise any errors, training is not being conducted, parameters are not updated.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


# A simple model
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()        
        self.params = nn.Parameter(data=torch.randn(18, 512))
        
    def forward(self):
        return self.params


# A list of N Model objects
N = 10
device = 'cuda'
models = [Model().to(device) for _ in range(N)]


# I need to forward the parameters of all N models from a subsequent network, calculate a loss and back-propagate
params = torch.cat([m().unsqueeze(0) for m in models], dim=0)  # torch.Size([10, 18, 512])

y = some_network(params)

# Calculate the loss
loss = some_loss(y)

# Back-propagate
loss.backward()
```

Obviously, I could define the parameters as

```py
params = torch.Parameter(data=torch.randn(N, 18, 512))
```

and do the rest without issues, but I have reasons to need each (18, 512)-dimensional parameters as the parameters of a **separate model.** Any insight on how this could be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are creating new instances of the Model class every time you call `m()` in the list comprehension to concatenate the parameters. This creates a new computation graph for each instance, which is not connected to the graph of the subsequent network you are using to calculate the loss and back-propagate.

you can fix the issue by calling the `params`

`params = torch.cat([m.params.unsqueeze(0) for m in models], dim=0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't appear to solve the issue. I had to pivot and define a class for all N parameters.